# DataCamp Light not working in flutter webview

Tags: r, flutter, webview, flutterwebviewplugin

I'm writing an app that displays a WebView in Flutter. For this purpose I added the [`webview_flutter`](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) package to my `pubspec.yaml` like this:

```
  dependencies:
    webview_flutter: "^0.3.18+1"
```

I want to display this url: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tutorial/vignettes/tutorial-basics.html

so I did the following:

```
class WebViewExample extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            child: WebView(
              initialUrl: 'https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tutorial/vignettes/tutorial-basics.html',
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              userAgent: "Google Chrome Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36.",
            )
        )
    );

  }
}
```

Everything works as expected except when I try to run the `R` code. The Datacamp fiddle tries to setup the workspace but then I get: "**Your session has been disconnected**" although It works well in the browser.

[image]

I also tried with the [`flutter_webview_plugin`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) with the same result.

Any advise to run this?

Comment: Did you try the set this property: `bool ignoreSSLErrors: false`. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin. This error may stem from SSL error?

Comment: Try to generate a simple HTML that generated with R and `tutorial` package then use this in your `initialUrl` instead of cran link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a completer for your `WebView`.and use it in the `onWebViewCreated()`

```
final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =Completer<WebViewController>();
WebView(
      initialUrl: selectedUrl,
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
        _controller.complete(webViewController);
      },
    )
```